# Dynamically name a column based on a WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic

**Objective:**

I am running a query on a weekly basis and would like one of my column to return the `ISO_WEEK` number with the prefix 'W'. For example: W1.

More specifically, I would like to reproduce the following condition into a column name.

```
DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, table.login) = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,GETDATE())-2
```

Main Query is:

```
 SELECT 
     CAST(t.log_time as Date)           AS Week1
    ,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,t.log_time)      AS Week_Number -- Dynamically named with ISO_WEEK
    ,email                              AS Emails
 FROM table.memberlog as t
 WHERE 1=1
    AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, t.log_time) = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,GETDATE())-2
    AND DATEPART(YEAR, t.log_time) = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411699/generate-column-name-dynamically-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate column name dynamically in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411699/generate-column-name-dynamically-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is declarative by design and does not support macro substitution.  This leaves you with Dynamic SQL such as  ...

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
SELECT 
     CAST(t.log_time as Date)           AS Week1
    ,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,t.log_time)      AS '+concat('W',DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,GETDATE())-2)+'
    ,email                              AS Emails
 FROM table.memberlog as t
 WHERE 1=1
    AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, t.log_time) = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,GETDATE())-2
    AND DATEPART(YEAR, t.log_time) = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())
'

Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: So to run my query, it needs to be in a DECLARE statement?

Comment: if you want the column name to change on the fly, then yes.